# Clear value of all input elements of a container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying the following code to clear the value of all inputs and textareas in the container div but it doesn't work:

```
var t = $('#container').clone();
t.find('input[type="text"],textarea').val('');
alert(t.html()); //the inputs in the alert have value
```

Neither this works:

```
t.find('input[type="text"],textarea').each(function () { $(this).val(''); });
```

The idea is to have a clone of the container with empty input elements.

Comment: `alert(t).html(); //the inputs in the alert have value` – you are confusing HTML code and DOM.

Comment: What's the purpose of this? You can reset `form`s by using an `input` tag with the attribute `type="reset"`.

Comment: @jaunt the inputs should preserve their values for later, but I need same form with empty inputs

Comment: Append the cloned object to DOM and empty it.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani: (1) The `.val('')` doesn't remove the attribute, it simply changes the property. Hence the original HTML markup will remain unchanged. Whether you clone it or not, it doesn't matter. (2) If you want to clear the inputs for use afterwards, why not just use them first and see. Just append them to the container and you will them being cleared. What do you really need the `.html()` for? -- See this - http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ayhvudg7/

Comment: @Abhitalks I have these inputs on a container and their values are the project properties (name, path, ...) however I want to show the empty form when "create new project" is clicked but however the user may cancel new project creation and the form (that is opened as dialog) should still contain the current project properties. the the reason I need the .html is that the dialog plugin I use gets the content as string. like this: `content: t.html()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `value` attribute you see in the alert is a default value for the `input`. It is not cleared when you use `val`, hence you see it in the HTML, and alert.

If you were to write the HTML itself to the document, you would see the value is cleared: [like here](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/dLm4xwvh/).

If you want to clear the default as well, you can use the jQuery `attr` method

```
.attr("value", "")
```

to clear that. [Like here](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/dLm4xwvh/1/)

Works just as well for [textarea](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/dLm4xwvh/2/)

---

PS, from [docs](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

> **Note:** Using .clone() has the side-effect of producing elements with duplicate id attributes, which are supposed to be unique. Where possible, it is recommended to avoid cloning elements with this attribute or using class attributes as identifiers instead.

Comment: Awesome the only problem remains is the textarea, how should I clear it?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani should work the same, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

You can try below.

```
var clone = $('#container').clone().attr('id',    'newid');
clone.find('[type=text]').val('').attr("value","").text("");
clone.find('textarea').val('').text("");
alert(clone.html());
```